# Cant get RETURNS function to work

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to get the RETURNS to work. I've indicated the order type, but script only recognizing the delivery type. I want returns to be priced at price + 20, using the STANDARD parameters.

How do I fix it? It looks like it isnt reading the "order type" parameter i set for the returns!

```
function calculate(deliveryType, orderType, timeslotType, size, weight, fromZone, toZone) {

    var price = 0.0

    var params = {
        from: fromZone.getBillingZone(),
        to: toZone.getBillingZone()
    }

    var record = undefined

    if (orderType == "NORMAL" || "C2C") {

        record = util.zones.findRecord(deliveryType, params)

        if (size == "S") {
            return record.pouchRate
        }

    } else if (orderType == "RETURN") {

        record = util.zones.findRecord("STANDARD", params)

    } else {
        throw "Unknown order type " + orderType
    }

    if (deliveryType == "STANDARD") {
        price = price
    }

    if (deliveryType == "EXPRESS") {
        price = price
    }

    if (orderType == "RETURN") {
        price = price + 20.0
    }

    return price

    var standardCSV = expressCSV = [{
        "from": "else",
        "to": "else",
        "pouchRate": 50.0
    }, {
        "from": "else",
        "to": "there",
        "pouchRate": 60.0
    }]

    var nextDayCSV = [{
        "from": "else",
        "to": "else",
        "pouchRate": 70.0
    }]

    var sameDayCSV = [{
        "from": "else",
        "to": "else",
        "pouchRate": 90.0
    }]
```

Comment: You should provide a real [mcve]. That code won't compile, you haven't told us what input you are giving the function, you haven't told us what output you are getting, and you haven't told us what output you are expecting.

Comment: Your question says `RETURNS` but your code is checking for `RETURN` perhaps that could be your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong. `if (orderType == "NORMAL" || "C2C")` is always true (because `"C2C"` evaluates to true). What you probably want instead is:

```
if (orderType == "NORMAL" || orderType == "C2C")
```